# Writing a date from Excel VBA to a worksheet gives the wrong value

Tags: excel, time, vba

When I write a date from VBA into an Excel worksheet, sometimes the value on the worksheet ends up being one less (one day earlier) than I expect. Here's an example that I've tested on a multiple computers with Excel 2003, 2007, and 2010. From the immediate window:

```
?Format(41652.9999999963, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

> 2014-01-14 00:00:00

[A1].value = CDate(41652.9999999963)
?Format([A1].value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

> 2014-01-13 00:00:00

[A1].value = CDbl(CDate(41652.9999999963))
?Format([A1].value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

> 2014-01-14 00:00:00
```

What exactly triggers this?

**EDIT:**

Okay, let me be more clear that **this isn't a rounding issue.** If I go up or down one fraction of a second I get the correct time. It's just that if I hit near this exact number the date goes off by an entire day:

```
[A1].value = CDate(41652.99999)
?Format([A1].value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

> 2014-01-13 23:59:59

[A1].value = CDate(41652.999999999996)
?Format([A1].value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

> 2014-01-13 00:00:00

[A1].value = CDate(41652.999999999997)
?Format([A1].value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

> 2014-01-14 00:00:00

[A1].value = CDate(41653.00001)
?Format([A1].value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

> 2014-01-14 00:00:01
```

Comment: You are running into problems of rounding - numbers such as you are showing cannot be represented with all their accuracy in a typical floating point number. It's a common problem in computer science. If you really care whether 11:59:59.999999 is today or tomorrow, you need to pay attention to how rounding is done (and probably use a number that is zero at midnight, and goes from just negative to just positive, instead of using an offset of "since January 1970" or whatever Excel uses).

Comment: I think it must be getting converted into a single precision number at some point during the date conversion, copying into a cell, or formatting it back into a date.

Comment: @Floris I think you may have gotten the wrong impression - the dates aren't being rounded to the nearest day. If I move up or down by 2e-5 I get correct dates down to the second. It's just that when I hit that exact number the date moves backward by one whole day.

Comment: Yes thank you for clarifying. I could not reproduce this in Office 2011 on the Mac. Things "behaved themselves". Can you tell us what version of Excel you are using?

Comment: @Floris I've tried this on Excel 2003 for Win XP, 2010 for 7, and 2007 for Server 2008.

Comment: I can't replicate either it is correctly converting the value for me, Windows 7 Excel 2010. The only thing i noticed is it does also convert it to `CDate(41653#)` on me.

Comment: @user2140261 You have to do this from the immediate pane.

Comment: I can duplicate this effect with Excel 2003 and Vista. I am using a macro rather than the immediate window and I replace `Print` with `Debug.Print`. If stored in a worksheet using CDate, `41652.5` converts to `2014-01-13 12:00:00`, `41652.999988426` converts to `2014-01-13 23:59:59` but `41652.9999999963` converts to `2014-01-13 00:00:00`.  However, if I store the numbers directly and then use Format to display them as dates, I get the correct dates. That is: `41652.999988426` displays as `2014-01-14 00:00:00`.

Comment: Probably a bug of `CDate`? C Pearson has an implementations that converts times from Serial Format to Dates here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LocalAndGMTTimes.htm, which gives correct results for the above values. Not as versatile as `CDate` (eg, does not convert numbers stored as strings) but it works..

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Help for CDate, "CDate recognizes date literals and time literals as well as some numbers that fall within the range of acceptable dates. When converting a number to a date, *the whole number portion is converted to a date*. *Any fractional part of the number is converted to a time of day*, starting at midnight." It never says that time rounded to next day adds to dates!! I believe that this solves the mystery.

In fact you can use round yourself to get the desired result. Tests demonstrated that 9 digits are the top number for rounding, with 10 providing the undesired effect...

ex `[a1]=cdate(round(41652.9999999999,8))` --> 14/01/14 00:00

`[a1]=cdate(round(41652.9999999999,10))` --> 13/01/14 00:00

added code after comment:

```
Sub dower() 

Dim v1 As Double, vdt As Date, vv As Variant, vdbl As Double
Range("a1:a6").ClearContents

v1 = 41652.9999999996
vdt = CDate(v1)
vv = CDate(v1)
vdbl = CDate(v1)

[a1] = v1
[a2] = vdt
[a3] = vv
[a4] = vdbl

vdt = CDbl(v1)
[a5] = vdt

End Sub
```

Comment: But if it's a problem with `CDate`, why does it go away if I simply wrap `CDate`'s output with `CDbl`?

Comment: VB treats variables according to data. So it seems that wrapping cdate within cdbl ends in a double with intermediate calculations also stored in doubles. Run the added code to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

Both cell value and cdate have enough precision to story this value: 41652.9999999963.

```
?CDate(41652.9999999963) = 41652.9999999963
True
[A1].Value=cdbl(CDate(41652.9999999963))
?[A1].Value= 41652.9999999963
True
```

So I think this should be one Excel defect when user assign the cdate to cell value.

Though we don't know the detail implementaion of it, I can guess it might be look like:

```
[A1].Value=StringToDate(DateToString(CDate(41652.9999999963)))
```

When we do

```
[A1].Value=CDate(41652.9999999963))
```

And the "DateToString" function do not do the right thing: it cut the 41652.9999999963 into two part, 41652 and .9999999963 and it use 41652 to calculate the date part("2014-1-13"), and use .9999999963 to calculate the rest part ("1 day and 0:0:0"), then finally, they are merged into one value "2014-1-13 0:0:0" but "1 day" was lost.